# Ableton's Analog Voices

Tags: ableton, analog, voices

I have a question regarding the voices in Analog.

1. So when you turn on unisono and choose 2 voices, does that mean my original voice plus 2? Or 2 altogether?
2. When I use both oscillators then that means 1 voice?
3. When I have 1 OSC with a sawtooth wave and the other OSC with square wave and I put unisono on (2 voices for example). Do I have double the saw and double the square or what?
4. I learned that if you choose the polyphony (the voice count), say 8 voices and you have unisono on (4 voices) then you can only play 2 notes at a time. Not a chord of 3. But when I set the polyphony to mono. I still get the unisono effect. How the hell does this work?

Some insight would be greatly appreciated. Thx!